# HTML - user added variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way in HTML/javascript to make a user add a variable?

For example :
I have a list of usernames :

```
var username1 = "test1";
var username2 = "test2";
var username3 = "test3";
```

and a button :

```
<button type="submit" onclick="newUsername()">New</button>
```

I want the button to add a new variable  `username'x'` where `x` is the next number in the sequence (in this case 4).

Comment: how do you use the new created variables?

Comment: For what is this useful?

Comment: In this example what I'm thinking of is that this way you can have an infinite number of users.

Comment: Why do you want someone to press a button to generate a predictable list? What is this good for? Do you have a server application with a database that stores user accounts? If you really talk about users of your application, you'll need something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having different variables `username`, you can consider having an array you can iterate over. Consider the snippet below:

```js
var username=[];

var current = 0;

function newUsername(){
current++;
username.push({["username"+current]: "test"+current})
console.log(username);
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="newUsername()">New</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - by assigning a property to `window` which would make the variable global.

```js
const myVariableName = 'foo'
const myVariableValue = 'bar'
window[myVariableName] = myVariableValue

console.log(foo) // logs 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

1 (not recommended) have a variable that tells your code what number you are on then do something like this:

```
window['username'+userNameIndex] = newUsername;
```

Or

2 Place your username into an array:

```
var usernames = ['test1','test2','test3'];
```

And add the new username into the array:

```
username.push(newUserName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hold your usernames in an array with objects for example.

Let say:

```
var usernames = [{}]

function newUsername(text) {
   var arrLength = usernames.length || 0;
   usernames.push({ ["username" + arrLength]: text });
}

newUsername("test");
```

result: usernames[{username1: "test"}]